# How can I change the thumb height of Scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please tell me how to adjust the height of the scrollbar thumb?

I have tried  many different things like

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 10px;
}
```

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I have also read this answer [Change scrollbar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height) and [How to change the height of a scrollbar thumb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722357/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-scrollbar-thumb) but it didn't work. Some people in the answers said that it is not possible to change the height on the scrollbar thumb then how this site https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ is doing it?

My current code is

```css
body {
  height: 110vh;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #3EECAC;
    background-image: linear-gradient(19deg, #3EECAC 0%, #EE74E1 100%);
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: in a vertical scroll you cant set the height and similarily you cant set the width in horizontal scroll.

Comment: Are you on firefox? (I am) It doesn't work on firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar (or internet explorer)

Comment: Try going to this website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height Look at the answers, does the second one have a red scroll bar? If not it's not supported on your browser.

Comment: No, I am using Google Chrome

Comment: This is my project link https://epicmusicplayer.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: It works on my chrome

Comment: what you have used?
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 10px;
}
this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported on your browser then:

Ask this:

Are you on firefox?

Does the scrollbar change in stackoverflow: [Change scrollbar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height)

(Do the answers scrollbars change?)

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: No, I am using chrome

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: the answer which you have shared is working. 
I guess it is working because the text is very large

Comment: I am currently using Windows 10 2004